# how to keep in Sync with GIT repo on Mac OSX computer

Tags: git, macos, cron

I have a git server setup on an online VPS and I develop from my Mac Snow Leopard desktop. The VPS might go away at any point (and I don't feel like paying monthly subscription for private git repo) so I want to make sure that my repo in Sync at all times with the server.

What is the best way to do so? Do you recommend having some kind of cron job that runs say every hour to update my git on my development machine or some other computer. If so how to do so as I have never setup a cron job on Mac before.

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X has [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/MacOsX/launchd.html) which provides cron-like functionality.

However, if you're developing on your OS X machine, then the VPS *is* your backup, so you wouldn't be losing any data when the VPS goes away.  The only risk is when someone edits *on* the VPS.  The easiest solution is "don't do that".  :)